# Как с помощь арифметических действий найти максимально возможное и минимально возможное значение unsigned int?

Tags: c, битовые-операции

Пытаюсь использовать перевод в дополнительный код и побитовый сдвиг , но ничего не получается , и попытался написать перевод в дополнительный код и простой цикл,увеличивающий значение переменной до максимума

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
unsigned int convert(unsigned int max3) {
if (max3 < 0)
 max3 = ~(-max3) + 1;
return max3;
}
main(){
unsigned int max3;
    while(max3<max3+1){
        max3=max3+1;
    }
convert(max3);  
printf("%d",max3);
getch();
}
```

Comment: При чем здесь "битовые-операции" и чего именно вы пытались достичь своей функцией `convert` - не ясно.

Comment: @AnT, в википедии прочитал , что так можно двоичное число в дополнительном коде , И вот вопрос : когда вообще нужно использовать дополнительный код тогда?

Comment: @Elvin: Дополнительный код вам вообще не нужно использовать, если у вас нет на то каких-то специфических причин. Это уже у вас надо спрашивать, зачем вы сюда приплели "дополнительный код" и откуда он вообще взялся. У вас вопрос, вроде бы, про беззнаковый тип. У беззнаковых типов вообще нет и не может быть никакого "дополнительного кода". К чему он здесь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Минимальное значение для `unsigned int` "искать" не надо - это всегда заведомо `0`.

Максимальное значение для `unsigned int` - можно получить как значение `-1`, приведенное к типу `unsigned int`, то есть `(unsigned) -1`. Или просто

```
unsigned max = -1;
```

Его также можно получить как

```
unsigned max = 0;
--max;
```

если вам так больше нравится.

---

Для печати значений типа `unsigned int` в `printf` используется формат `%u`. Не `%d`, а именно `%u`.

Comment: а разве не  такое 4294967295 ?

Comment: @Elvin: Что "не такое"? Для 32-битного `unsigned int` выражение `(unsigned) -1` как раз и даст ваши `4294967295`.

Comment: что значит Для 32-битного unsigned int? И почему это (unsigned) -1 равно искомому и как тогда перевести такое ?

Comment: @Elvin: Ым... Ну тут надо уже азы изучать. Если на вашей платформе тип `unsigned int` имеет ширину в 16 бит, то его максимальное значение - `65535`, если 32 бита - то `4294967295`, если 64 бита - то `18446744073709551615`. И т.д. А то, почему `(unsigned) -1` равно максимальному значению этого типа вытекает из свойств беззнаковой арифметики в языке С. Беззнаковая арифметика в С - это арифметика по модулю `2^n`, где `n` - битовая ширина данного типа.

Comment: я думал , что этот минус впереди - знаковый бит, но как может быть знак в unsigned ? тогда я подумал , что это может быть просто прямой код и его перевод дополнительный  поможет мне избавиться от непонятного ответа - 1 , и хотелось бы все таки  получить 4294967295

Comment: Если вопрошаещему не нравится -1, то может `~0` его устроит?

Comment: @Elvin: "Ответ `-1`" у вас может получаться из-за того, что вы используете `%d` в `printf` для печати этого "ответа". Формат `%d` предназначен для типа  `int`. Именно `int`, а не `unsigned int`. Если вы хотите печатать `unsigned int`, то формат должен быть `%u`. Не `%d`, а `%u`.

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек, я совсем забыл про формат вывода

Comment: Формально `(unsigned int)(-1)` просто применяет тип к битовому представлению *отрицательного* числа, а стандарт тут допускает и дополнительный код, и обратный, и величину со знаком... Так что этот способ годится только в большинстве случаев (с дополнительным представлением отрицательных чисел), но не для всех. А вот вариант выстроить максимальное значение как вида 111...111 - годится, потому что беззнаковые подчиняются обычной арифметике по модулю 2<sup>n</sup> (стандарт, 3.9.1.7 и 3.9.1.4).

Comment: @Harry: Ни в коем случае. Никакого "просто применяет тип к битовому представлению отрицательного числа" в языке С ы принципе. Это противоречит самой философии С. Правила приведения знакового значения к беззнаковому четко описаны в 6.3.1.3 и никаких "просто применяет" тут нет. Более того, `(unsigned int)(-1)` гарантированно дает `UINT_MAX` на всех платформах, в т.ч. использующих альтернативные знаковые представления, что, понятное дело, полностью исключает вариант ""просто применяет тип к битовому представлению".

Comment: Вариант `1111...11` - работает, но несколько хуже, ибо не позволяет записать правую часть в виде простого типонезависмого rvalue (каковым является `-1`). Чтобы получить последовательность из правильного числа `1` придется тем или иным способом привязаться к конкретной ширине типа. К тому же привлечение побитовых операций там, где достаточно арифметических - это всегда некузяво. Именно поэтому вариант с `-1` - общепринятая идиома, а вариант с `111...11` практически не встречается.

Comment: Вариант с 1111 дает число либо больше предыдущего, либо такое же (достигнут максимум). Увы, но в моих :) стандартах 6.3.1.3 вообще отсутствует, 6.3 - Compound statement or block.

Comment: @Harry: О каком "достигнут максимум" идет речь? Вариант какого-то "итеративного" поиска максимума мной не рассматривался вообще, ибо никакого смысла в нем нет. Зачем *искать* максимум, если есть элементарный способ получить его сразу?

Comment: Потому что я пока не нашел в стандарте приведенный вами пункт :) А, блин! Я искал в С++, извините...

Comment: В С++ это 4.8/2. Буквальные формулировки там используются разные, но смысл один и тот же. Преобразование делается с сохранением конгруэнтности по модулю `2^N`

Comment: Эээ... в моем стандарте - 4.7 :) Убедили.

Comment: @avp, `~0`, во-первых, требует модификатора (U[L[L]]), а это в свою очередь может повлечь за собой warning без явного приведения типа.

Comment: @0andriy, конечно, всякие бывают компиляторы. Ну, а `gcc.real (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)` на код от `char c = ~0;` до `unsigned long long ull = ~0;`, вызванный `gcc t.c -Wall -std=c11` (и с др -std тоже) не ругается и прога исправно печатает `ff` в нужном количестве. (кстати, g++ тоже все это спокойно ест)